# How to perform array unrolling in LLVM using the C++ API?

Tags: c++

I am currently working on writing a compiler in C++ using the LLVM API.

One feature of the language that the compiler is being built for is that it supports operating on an entire array at once if no index is supplied:

```
variable myArray = integer[3];

myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
myArray[2] = 3;

// myArray now equals [1, 2, 3]

// Here is the whole array operation
// myArray should now equal [2, 4, 6]
myArray = myArray * 2;
```

Currently I have global (llvm global variables) and local variables, and when an array is being declared global, operations that involve modifying the entire array at once do not work. It appears that my code modifies only the first element of the array and then fills the rest of the array with 0's. However my code works for local arrays which is confusing to me.

Does anyone have any experience performing this kind of operation using the LLVM API and if so could you please help? I will attach some of my code in case it is of any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is basically "help me debug this", and such questions are rarely gets answered. Nor they are useful for the rest of the community. So, I'll try to help both you and future readers by giving some general thoughts.

The `myArray = myArray * 2;` construct in your language is a **syntactic sugar** for a usual boring loop. It is a great candidate for **desugaring**, that is a source-level (or higher IR level, if you have that) transformation. By transforming it to a loop in your language, you wouldn't need any special codegen on the LLVM side. And lowering it with special codegen rule, like now, is much more error-prone, as you can already see.

As for debugging, I can only recommend compiling minimal program featuring the bug into LLVM IR and then using `lli` tool as a debugger.